# Sum of eigenvalues is eigenvalue in which case?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Question:  Given, $A$ is $4×4$ matrix with real entries such that $-1, 1, 2,-2$ are eigenvalue of $A$ and $B$ is matrix such that $B= A^4 -5A^2 +5I$ where $I$ is $4×4$ identity matrix then eigenvalues of $B$ are?

My teacher has written on board that, the eigenvalues of $B$ are $1-5+5, 1-5+5, 16-20+5, 16-20+5$.

I could not get it!! How it was written?

I just know that, as $-1,1,2,-2$ are eigenvalues of $A$.

So eigenvalues of $A^2$ are $1, 1,4,4$

& Eigenvalues of $A^4$ are $1, 1, 16, 16$

& Eigenvalue of $I$ is $1$ with algebraic multiplicity $4$.

So how they obtained eigenvalues of $B$? I know that if $a$ is eigenvalue of $A$ and $b$ is eigenvalue of $B$ then $a+b$ need not be an eigenvalues of $A+B$. 
Please help me.

Comment: I think it's simpler to notice that $B=I$. We know that the eigenvalues of $A$ are $1,-1,2,-2$ thus giving the minimal/characteristic polynomial of $A$ as, $$f(x)=(x-1)(x+1)(x-2)(x+2)=(x^2-1)(x^2-4)=x^4-5x^2+4$$ Now, by the [Cayley Hamilton Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley–Hamilton_theore), we have $f(A)=0$. Now, notice that $B=f(A)+I$, so we conclude that $B=I$ which has all 4 eigenvalues equal to $1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eigenvalues are additive *when the corresponding eigenvector is the same* - that is, if $Av = \lambda_1v$ and $Bv = \lambda_2v$, then $(A + B)v = Av + Bv = \lambda_1v + \lambda_2v = (\lambda_1 + \lambda_2)v$. Notice that an eigenvector for $A$ is automatically an eigenvector for $A^n$ for any $n$, with corresponding eigenvalue $\lambda^n$ if $\lambda$ was the corresponding eigenvalue of $A$. So in particular, this approach will work whenever all matrices involved are powers of a single matrix.

In this case, we have that if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ with corresponding eigenvector $v$, then $Bv = (A^4 - 5A^2 + 5I)v = A^4v - 5A^2v + 5Iv = \lambda^4v - 5\lambda^2v + 5v = (\lambda^4 - 5\lambda^2 + 5)v$; so $\lambda^4 - 5\lambda^2 + 5$ is an eigenvalue of $B$.

Comment: Thanks u so much. I got it.

Answer (score 1):

Use the fact that the eigenvectors for $A$ will also be eigenvectors for $B$.

Suppose $Av = \lambda v$. Then $Bv = (A^4-5A^2+5I)v = \lambda^4v - 5 \lambda^2v + 5v.$ Now, just plug in your appropriate value of $\lambda$ to get the scaling factor of $B$ on $v$. You will do this four times, once for each eigenvalue to get the final result.

Comment: Please can you explain in more details

Comment: I think you've got it now from the other reply - it's basically the same idea.